# Which is faster for a small amount of information, java file i/o or derby?

Tags: java, file, performance, io, derby

I'm writing a small agent in java that will play a game against other agents. I want to keep a small amount of state (probably approx. 1kb at most) around between runs of the program so that I can try to tweak the performance of the agent based upon past successes. Essentially, I will be reading a small amount of data at the beginning of each game and writing a small amount at the end. It seems like I have 2 options, file I/O or derby. Is there a speed advantage to either? Or does it not really matter for such a small amount of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that these objects can vary per file size, and your computer's specs (bus speed, HD speed) affect this, the only way to be sure is to write your own benchmark.  Just create a simple for loop, count from 1 to 1000, and read the file inside the loop over and over (but do not create and destroy the objects inside the loop, just focus on the reading part).

Of course this whole exercise reeks of pre-optimization, which can lead to bad coding habit.  Just write your code in the most readable, simple fashion, and if there is a speed problem, refactor as needed.

But since it's a small amount of data, I would say it won't matter.

Comment: yeah, that's kind of what I figured.

Answer (score 2):

With 1kb of data, you are better off using standard file IO. Most likely, you could serialize the entire object tree to disk and dismply deserialize when you startup again. If you wanted to get fancy, you could use JAXB to serialize to XML instead of binary files.

As much as I love to fit every problem to the database solution, I don't think that's very practical here. Unless you have some special need of database specific capabilities, you are introducting a lot of overhead, complexity, maintenance problems by using a database.

The only areas where you might really want to use the database is if you have a lot of small objects/rows and you frequently perform sorts and filters on the data. But even then, you could probably keep a dozen in-memory ordered lists and get better performance with less resources and without the headache of a database.

If you really think you need a database in this scenario, consider HSQL. I don't consider it a real database, but it's a in-memory database that can persist to a file. Low overhead, low complexity, and relatively few points of failure. Plus, if you need to edit the persisted data, you can do so with a text editor. Can't say that about Derby.